# How to convert AMD define with ace editor to webpack?

Tags: webpack, requirejs, amd, ace-editor

I try to migrate an old project based on AMD / require.js and Ace editor to webpack. After I have run webpack I get the following errors and I cannot figure out how to fix them.

output:

```
ERROR in ./src/lib/custom-ace.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ace' in '.../src/lib'
 @ ./src/lib/custom-ace.js 2:0-12:2
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/lib/custom-ace.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '.../src/lib'
 @ ./src/lib/custom-ace.js 2:0-12:2
 @ ./src/index.js
```

src/index.js

```
require(["lib/custom-ace"], function(customAce) {
    editor = customAce.createEditor({})
})
```

src/lib/custom-ace.js:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ace' // <-- is this correct?
], function(jQuery, ace) {

    var exports = {};

    exports.createEditor = function(options) {
    }
    return exports;
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "ace": "^1.3.0",
    "ace-builds": "^1.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.33.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: [
        path.resolve('./node_modules'),
        'src/lib/*.js',
        path.resolve('./src')
      ],
      extensions: ['.js'] // File types
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ace from package.json since it is not

```
import ace from "ace-builds"
ace.edit(element, options)
```

if you want to automatically load modes, install the file-loader webpack plugin and use

```
import "ace-builds/webpack-resolver"
```

similar to https://github.com/nightwing/ace-webpack-demo